# How to handle expire refresh token in box api

Tags: oauth, box-api

Box api refresh token would expire if the token is not used for 14 days.

So how would I know the refresh token has been expired? Any exception would be thrown in android box api? Or what I need to do is to show the login view again?

UPDATE:
i know that android sdk would auto refresh access token using refresh token. But how about the refresh token, how to handle its expiration?

Thanks

Comment: @PlatformBoxer Sorry, Could you mind updating you answer according to the comment, please? Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

The next API call with return an error, and the details will tell you that the authorization token has expired.

When that happens, you should call the [/tokens](http://developers.box.com/docs/#oauth-2-token) endpoint to do a refresh grant.  See more details in [OAuth2](http://developers.box.com/oauth/) tutorials in the section on "Using the Access and Refresh Tokens"

Also, note that we've extended the refresh token to be valid for 60 days.   It is still a 1-time use token, but even if your users don't use your application for 59 days, it will still work to get them a new Access Token.

Comment: Sorry,  just want clarification, I am asking refresh token instead of access token

Comment: i know that andrkid sdk would auto refresh access token.  But how about the refresh token

Comment: Can you please provide an example of code?